# How does {item1, item2} == {item3, item4} work in Python?

Tags: python

I'm solving a Python challenge which I answered it like this:

```
def areEquallyStrong(yourLeft, yourRight, friendsLeft, friendsRight):
    return (yourLeft == friendsLeft or yourLeft == friendsRight) 
        and (yourRight == friendsLeft or yourRight == friendsRight)
```

I wonder if its equivalent to

```
def areEquallyStrong(yourLeft, yourRight, friendsLeft, friendsRight):
    return {yourLeft, yourRight} == {friendsLeft, friendsRight}
```

I don't precisely know what the `{} == {}` is doing under the hood and how it's being compared.

Comment: set comparison. `{6,3}=={3,6}` will return `True`

Comment: `{} == {}` you are comparing two `set`s (if you don't know sets yet, imagine it is a list, unordered and without duplicates). For instance: `{1,2} == {2,1}` is True.

Comment: No, these are not equivalent. Try passing `3, 3, 3, 1` to both functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the builtin `type` function is useful here:

```py
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
>>> type({1, 2})
<class 'set'>
```

We can conclude that `{}` in your case is not a dictionary, but a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). A set is an unordered sequence of values, in which each element is unique (if you do `print({2, 2})` the output will be `{2}`). `{1, 2} == {1, 2}` does a `set` comparison. Basically, it checks if the two sets were the same if they were ordered.
But, the two code snippets won't give the same result, because, in the first you are checking if both `yourLeft` and `yourRight` equal one of `friendsLeft` and `friendsRight`, and in the second you aren't. You would be better off with putting `friendsLeft` and `friendsRight` in a list and checking if both `yourLeft` and `yourRight` are present in that list:

```py
def areEquallyStrong(yourLeft, yourRight, friendsLeft, friendsRight):
    return yourLeft in [friendsLeft, friendsRight] and yourRight in [friendsLeft, friendsRight]
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, `{item1, item2}` creates a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). A set object is an unordered collection of distinct objects. Duplicated items will be removed when creating a set or adding items to a set.

Equivalence comparison between two sets yields `True` if they contains exactly the same elements.

You can try it like:

```
>>> s1 = {1, 2, 3, 1}
>>> s2 = {3, 2, 1}
>>> s1
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s2
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s1 == s2
True
```

Notes:

1. To be precise, the objects in a set must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable).
2. While `s = {item1, item2}` creates a set, `s = {}` does not create an empty set. Instead, it creates an empty [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). To create an empty set, use `s = set()`.

Answer (score 1):

`{} == {}` is a set comparison. Python’s built-in `set` type are unordered and unique. Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is contained in the other

Answer (score 0):

you can use max and min to check these

```
def areEquallyStrong(yourLeft, yourRight, friendsLeft, friendsRight):
    if max(yourLeft,yourRight) == max(friendsLeft,friendsRight) and 
       min(yourLeft,yourRight) == min(friendsLeft,friendsRight):
       return True
    else:
       return False
```